# how to hide a ImageButton in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I want to make an ImageButton visible or invisible depending on a variable. More precisely, as soon as I click on a button it appears and as soon as I click again it disappears how can I do it?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ImageButton inherits from the View class, thus it should have IsVisible property available. Try it out ? If this doesn't work, try `button.Visibility=ViewStates.Gone` or `button.Visibility=ViewStates.Invisible`

**Gone** will remove element from object tree completely

**Invisible** will just make it not visible (but still take place)